# Return HTML Element from PHP Script Response based on Condition

Tags: php

I'm trying to write a script as a cronjob in order to implement notifications in my website. I'm checking whether or not the stock count on products are at half capacity. The script works but it returns `<p>No New Notifications</p>` as well as the product name if the capacity is at half. Am I doing something wrong. I'm trying to only return one or the other. How can I improve my script to do this

```php
<?php

include 'DB.php';

$SQL = "SELECT Product_Name, Stock_Count, Stock_Remaining 
        FROM Products 
        WHERE Stock_Count > 0";

$result = $conn->query($SQL);

if ($result->num_rows > 0 ){
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
       if ($row["Stock_Count"] / 2 == $row["Stock_Remaining"]){
           echo "<p>$row[Product_Name] is at half capacity</p>";
       }else{
           echo "<p>No New Notifications</p>";
       }
    }
}else {
    echo "No Products Found";
}
```

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241538/discussion-on-question-by-pureware-legends-of-gaming-return-html-element-from-p).

Comment: Okay good. Of course it is also interesting for this platform what the error was. So that others can learn from it.

Comment: If the issue is fixed you might like to edit the question to let others know the resolution or delete the question if there is little merit in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed `==` to `<=` which now only prints what I need to print

```php
<?php

include 'DB.php';

$SQL = "SELECT Product_Name, Stock_Count, Stock_Remaining FROM Products WHERE Stock_Count > 0";

$result = $conn->query($SQL);

if ($result->num_rows > 0 ){
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
       if ($row["Stock_Count"] / 2 <= $row["Stock_Remaining"] ){
           echo "<p>$row[Product_Name] is below half capacity</p>";
       }else {
           "<p>[$row[Product_Name]]: No New Notifications</p>";

       }
    }
}else {
    echo "No Products Found";
}
```